# Automatically compile Rails assets (using Sprockets) for Jasmine (jasmine-browser-runner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I finally moved our Rails application away from the old `jasmine-rails` Rails gem to the new `jasmine-core` and `jasmine-browser-runner` for Javascript testing. All works fine except that it seems that I'm now always required to:

- delete previously compiled assets (to prevent that the `"srcFiles": [ "application-*.js" ]` configuration has the test server load all previously compiled versions to `application.js`)
- precompile the assets again (that are delivered via Sprockets)
- restart the Express test server with `npx jasmine-browser-runner`

Since the old `jasmine-rails`-way was to use the existing application server, the asset pipeline compilations were done automatically, so that any change in the Javascript code would instantly be testable in Jasmine. Who know of a good way to setup `jasmine-browser-runner` such that it only takes one command to have the server running and have source file updates be immediately testable?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a Jasmine test runner (`bin/jasmine`) that will perform the required steps before running the specs once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Pass in parameter -i to simply start the test server so that you can run
# the test in a browser by going to localhost:8888. 
# This enables you to debug the code.

# Pass in parameter -h to run the tests in headless Chrome.

# Make sure to configure the right SRC_DIR and SRC_FILES for your project

require 'fileutils'
include FileUtils

SRC_DIR = ['public/test-assets']
SRC_FILES = ['jasmine-src-*']

# path to your application root.
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
COMPILED_ASSETS_DIR = File.join(APP_ROOT, SRC_DIR)

def system!(*args)
  system(*args) || abort("\n== Command #{args} failed ==")
end

if File.directory? COMPILED_ASSETS_DIR
  chdir COMPILED_ASSETS_DIR do
    puts '== Removing previously compiled versions of source files =='
    system "rm #{SRC_FILES.join(' ')}"
  end
end

puts '== Precompiling assets =='
system! 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails assets:precompile'

mode = ARGV.include?('-i') ? 'serve' : 'runSpecs'
headless_browser = mode == 'runSpecs' && ARGV.include?('-h') ? '--browser=headlessChrome' : ''

puts "== Running specs =="
system! "npx jasmine-browser-runner #{mode} #{headless_browser}"
```

Note that the script above compiles the assets in the test environment. By setting the assets directory in the test environment to a different one than in the development environment, we prevent the compiled assets from getting in the way of the development assets. In the script above we assume that we have the following configuration in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/test-assets"
```